# How to change the background color of a list item at click on a button?

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView and a CustomAdapter. The elements are all successfully loaded into the list. Now I want to change the background color of a certain element of the list by clicking on an external button. But I do not know how to access a specific item in the list.

Here is the CustomAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private int resource;
    private List<ItemModel> items;


    public PreorderListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemModel> items){
        this.ctx = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemModel getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        }


        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        TextView text3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);

        ItemModel item = items.get(i);

        text1.setText(item.getName());
        text2.setText(item.getOption2());
        text3.setText(item.getOption3());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this inside your `getView()` method

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   { 
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
         { 
           view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor));
          }
   });
```

If you have a button on your view then performs the listener on that button

If you want to get your selected item view from your parent activity then :

```
yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{ 
 @Override 
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>     parent,View view, int position, long id) 
    { 
       selectedposition = position ;
     }
  });


  View view = listView.getAdapter().getView(selectedposition,null,listview);
```

Then change its background:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor));
```

please define your color in your color.xml file

If you have more than one view then , create an `ArrayList<View>` and do some loop

Comment: I do not want to click an item. I would like to click an external button in my MainActivity.

Comment: Okei , so you have to select that item first right ?

Comment: Create a listener in your adapter with specific methods like :

Comment: No. In MainActivity I determine which position I need in the list. I do not manually pick the list item.

Comment: Thats what im getting: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can we switch to a chat please then i can guide you quickly

Comment: yeah your are new , you dont have this ability , but any way can you post the code of your ativity please

Comment: Can we maybe chat on facebook?

Comment: im sorry dont have facebook , but try to pur your code in a edit in your question ,to know which variable cause the nullPointerException

Comment: I just added the line:                     listview.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
and got the error above.

Comment: Look at my edit please and try the new way to get the view

Comment: I dont want to click on the items to select them. I already have the index of the item thats background i want to change. I tried this:
View view = listView.getAdapter().getView(selectedposition,null,listview);
view.setBackgroundColor(yourColor) 
There is no error anymore, but the background color doesnt change.

Comment: because your are using an int resource and not a color , try my edit please : view.setBackgroundResource

Comment: its a int resources that defines a color

Comment: view.setBackgroundResource(Color.GREEN); is throwing following exception:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff00ff00

Comment: check my edit setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor));

Comment: Im so sorry for wasting your time.. The color still doesnt change. Do i have to refresh the list or something like this?

Comment: no please write your activity code in the edit then i can read it , i figure out what is the issue

Comment: could you check your mails. i wrote you an email.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom listener interface in your activity and your 
    adapter will implement this.

```
public interface OnClickListenerFromActivity {
    void onActivityButtonClick(int position);
}
```

on click in your button call your listener's method

```
    mOnClickListenerFromActivity.onActivityButtonClick(mList.getItem(yourPostion));
```

implement this listener into your adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Activity.OnClickListenerFromActivity {

private Context ctx;
private int resource;
private List<ItemModel> items;


public PreorderListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemModel> items){
    this.ctx = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public ItemModel getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }


    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    TextView text3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);

    ItemModel item = items.get(i);

    text1.setText(item.getName());
    text2.setText(item.getOption2());
    text3.setText(item.getOption3());

    return view;
}

public void onActivityButtonClick(int position) {
    // get your item through position and
    // set your color here
}
```

}